# Unable to find page elements because "Element is no longer valid"

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver

Selenium is throwing exceptions when finding elements that are on the page. It is complaining that "Element is no longer valid".

For example, on a page with a drop down list, when I select an option there are tables that I need to find. For the first few options I find the table, but eventually searching for the elements causes an exception.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25));

IList<IWebElement> tableTRCollection = null;
IList<IWebElement> tableTDCollection;
bool exist = false;

while(!exist)
{
  try
  {
    tableTRCollection = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='t1']/tbody/tr"));
    exist = true;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Wait(1);
  }
}

for (int k = 0; k < tableTRCollection.Count; k++) 
{ 
  tableTDCollection = tableTRCollection[k].FindElements(By.TagName("td")); // -> Element is no longer valid
}
```

I loop over this entire block of code once per dropdown option. The first couple of times it's all ok. The next time through I see this:

- it exits the while loop (it found the table and `tableTRCollection`)
- it enters the for loop (`tabletTRCollection` contains at least one row)
- `tableTRCollection[k].FindElements(By.TagName("td"))` throws the "Element is no longer valid" exception.

I tried Selenium's wait functions but the result is the same.
What is causing the `tableTRCollection[k]` element to be no longer valid? The page is not changing.

Comment: which exception you getting?

Comment: for (int k = 1; k < tableTRCollection.Count; k++)
                            {

                                tableTDCollection = tableTRCollection[k].FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
Element is no longer valid

Comment: Do you want to get all TD of pages or All TD from particular TR section?

Comment: all TD'S from particular TR (When i doing wait for 3 sec before initializing trCollection everything works great) but cons wait time is not right.

Comment: Then you can use explicit wait and tell web driver that wait until all TDs loads.

Comment: the question is why the element is no longer exists (the page didn't changes.)

Comment: tried the explicit  the same result but the problem is that trcollection not longer exist how can i found in td's in not existing element.

Comment: then you should check first like `tableTRCollection.size()>0` , Not sure about syntax in c#. just check length of TRs before finding it.

Comment: still the same problem in the second drop down list chose after wait for a table when its gets the trCollection all of them with exceptions.

Comment: Please share a link to the page or the relevant HTML. Please rephrase the question so that it's clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: This has been happening to me lately, always due to the page changing in subtle ways. For example, selecting an item from the dropdown may have caused an ajax request resulting in a new table being created, thus destroying the old rows. If the new table looks like the old one, then it's easy to fail to see the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On pages where selecting from a dropdown list causes changes to the DOM (javascript magic, AJAX request, etc.), then the elements you find immediately after selecting may be gone by the time you use them to find more elements. The simple timeline might be:

1. Select item from dropdown
2. Find element X
3. Do some work
4. DOM changes
5. Call `X.FindElement(...)`
6. Exception happens.

The page might not look like it has changed, but Selenium is sensitive to all DOM changes and will complain.

You can usually work around this by using `driver.FindElements()` directly, instead of `element.FindElements()`. You will probably have to be clever with your `By.CssSelector()` or `By.Xpath()`, if you're using those.